# Making a Timeline/Linking Label Text to MsgBox

Tags: excel, button, charts, timeline, msgbox

I am creating a timeline in Excel. For each date, I could have one or more event happen. Displaying the entire text of each event above the data point will be crowded. I will have short descriptions above each data point. I want to click the label text or data point and have a message box appear with the information associated with that event.

I have a timeline template already and I have the values set up. I don't want to manually create transparent command buttons behind each event. Is there a way to have VBA automatically border or create a shape behind each data point or data label and have it be a button that displays a message box? Even better yet,  is there a simpler way of doing this process than I have been thinking about it?

Thank you so much!
Jaxon

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495461/add-hover-labels-to-a-scatter-chart-that-has-its-data-range-updated-dynamically

Comment: pnuts: I can put comments in the cells, but they won't show up on the data points of the timeline.

Comment: Orbling: I will look into the hover labels, but my knowledge of VBA is limited. It will take some time to understand. Thank you.